# Cannot unpack a file with sudo cpio

Tags: linux, sudo, redhat-enterprise-linux, cpio

```
I have sudo permissions and I'm trying to unpack a file with cpio command.
However, because of the path properties I get permission denied when I try to do it.

$ id
uid=4777(testuser) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),1008(otherwheel)

The home path has 700 permission:
$ sudo ls -ld /home/uadmin/
[sudo] password for testuser:
```

**drwx------. 16 uadmin uadmin 4096 dic  1 15:26 /home/uadmin/**

```
The file has 775 permission:
$ sudo ls -l /home/uadmin/RH7HOTFIX/INSTALL
[sudo] password for testuser:
```

**-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 163840 abr 28  2016 /home/uadmin/RH7HOTFIX/INSTALL**

```
When I try to unpack the file I get 'permission denied':
$ sudo cpio -ivcBdum install</home/uadmin/RH7HOTFIX/INSTALL
```

**-bash: /home/uadmin/RH7HOTFIX/INSTALL: permission denied**

```
I can´t change the path permission.
I can´t move the file because of the disk space.
I can´t use sudo -i for a new shell.

My OS is Red Hat Enterprise 7.2

Any ideas?
Thanks in advanced.
DASM
```

Comment: Dang, I just learned a new Linux command... (`id`).

Answer (score 1):

## sudo and shell redirection is broken

[Here's a good explanation and some workarounds:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/82278)

> Your command does not work because the redirection is performed by
> your shell which does not have the permission to write to
> [the file]. The redirection of the output is not performed by
> sudo.
>
> 1. Run a shell with sudo and give the command to it by using the -c
>    option
> 2. Create a script with your commands and run that script with sudo
> 3. Launch a shell with sudo -s then run your commands
> 4. Use sudo tee (if you have to escape a lot when using the -c option)

### 7-zip

Alternately, you could unpack the archive using a program that does not require shell redirection, such as [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), which should be available for RHEL 7 via rpmforge.

Here's a [HowTo](http://geekyadmins.com/unzip-7z-file-centos-7/):

> 1. Download the repo using the command given below.
>
> `sudo wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm`
>
> 2. Now install the downloaded rpm using
>
> `sudo rpm -ivh rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm`
>
> 3. Now you need to install the package
>
> `sudo yum install p7zip`
>
> 4. To unzip the file use the following command
>
> `sudo 7za x <filename>`

Comment: Thanks Hydraxan14.
Creating a script worked successfully.
The other options don´t work because my account is not allowed to execute /bin/bash or /bin/sh.

Thanks for the help.
DASM

Comment: @The-0m3n Welcome!  Please click on the checkmark underneath my answer to mark your question as solved.